# Extracting numbers from a string in python 1.5.2

Tags: python

I'm currently working with a Telit module (GT864-py) and I'm trying to extract numbers from a return value/string that I recieve when using AT-commands.

This is an example of the code that I'm using:

```
MDM.send('AT#ADC=1,2'+'\r', 5)
pump = MDM.receive(15)
pumpb = int(filter(str.isdigit, pump))
```

which gives the response

```
#ADC: 10 (This number can range from ~10-150)
OK
```

Now, I would like to filter the number after ADC, however, I have not yet found a solution as to how.

By using this code in PythonWin 1.5.2+ I get the following error:

NameError: isdigit

So I am assuming isdigit isn't supported in Python 1.5.2, is that correct? And if so, does anyone know any other ways to extract the numbers after #ADC: xxx ?

Comment: Why are you using 1.5.2? You could write your own `isdigit` using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), I suppose.

Comment: I guess you will have more success if you contact Python's IRC channel if you want to find users that have experienced this ancient Python version first hand.

Comment: IIRC Python 1.5.2 already had regexps... But really, Python 1.5.2 ??? That was early 1999 or so ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `all` doesn't exist either :-)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I suspected as much, but the docs show how to implement it at least!

Comment: The reason that I am using Python 1.5.2 is that the Telit module itself has a built-in python v 1.5.2 interpreter which, unfortunately, can't be updated to a later version. If it had a later version, say 2.7, this would have been a lot easier but now I'm left with trying to figure out a way to make it work on this old, obsolete piece of machinery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python 1.5.2p2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/) is available online. Indeed, there is no `isdigit` in either `str` or in the module [`string`](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/lib/module-string.html).

---

Even in Python 1.5, `str` is a sequence that supports the `in` operation, so you could do:

```
def isdigit(c):
    return c in '0123456789'

pumpb = int(filter(isdigit, pump))
```

---

For more thorough parsing I'd use a regular expression, with module [`re`](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/lib/module-re.html) instead; the code

```
import re
match = re.search('#ADC:\s*(\d+)', pump)
if match:
    number = match.group(1)
```

This will match `#ADC:` followed by any number of spaces, followed by 1 or more digits `[0-9]`; the digits are captured in the group `1`, whose value is then stored to `number` if a match was found.

Comment: After initial testing, this seems to work perfectly.I will try it more extensively with different numbers later but for now, a big thanks to you Mr. Haapala

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always exactly `"#ADC: "`, then simple string slicing should also work:

```
if pump[:6] == '#ADC: ':
    pumpb = int(pump[6:])
```